# Javascript translation/explaination

Tags: javascript, forms

If someone could be so kind and help me understand this script, it would be heavily appreciated.

What does it mean and what does it do?

```
<iframe style='display:none;width:0px; height:0px;' src='about:blank'
name='gform_ajax_frame_2' id='gform_ajax_frame_2'></iframe>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function gformInitSpinner_2() {
    jQuery('#gform_2').submit(function () {
      jQuery('#gform_submit_button_2').attr('disabled', true).after('<' + 'img id="gform_ajax_spinner_2"  class="gform_ajax_spinner" src="content/plugins/gravityforms/images/spinner.gif" alt="" />');
      jQuery('#gform_wrapper_2 .gform_previous_button').attr('disabled', true);
      jQuery('#gform_wrapper_2 .gform_next_button').attr('disabled', true).after('<' + 'img id="gform_ajax_spinner_2"  class="gform_ajax_spinner" src="content/plugins/gravityforms/images/spinner.gif" alt="" />');
    });
  }
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    gformInitSpinner_2();
    jQuery('#gform_ajax_frame_2').load(function () {
      var contents = jQuery(this).contents().find('*').html();
      var is_postback = contents.indexOf('GF_AJAX_POSTBACK') >= 0;
      if (!is_postback) {
        return;
      }
      var form_content = jQuery(this).contents().find('#gform_wrapper_2');
      var is_redirect = contents.indexOf('gformRedirect(){') >= 0;
      jQuery('#gform_submit_button_2').removeAttr('disabled');
      if (form_content.length > 0) {
        jQuery('#gform_wrapper_2').html(form_content.html());
        jQuery(document).scrollTop(jQuery('#gform_wrapper_2').offset().top);
        if (window['gformInitDatepicker']) {
          gformInitDatepicker();
        }
        if (window['gformInitPriceFields']) {
          gformInitPriceFields();
        }
        var current_page = jQuery('#gform_source_page_number_2').val();
        gformInitSpinner_2();
        jQuery(document).trigger('gform_page_loaded', [2, current_page]);
      } else if (!is_redirect) {
        var confirmation_content = jQuery(this).contents().find('#gforms_confirmation_message').html();
        if (!confirmation_content) {
          confirmation_content = contents;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
          jQuery('#gform_wrapper_2').replaceWith('<' + 'div id=\'gforms_confirmation_message\' class=\'gform_confirmation_message_2\'' + '>' + confirmation_content + '<' + '/div' + '>');
          jQuery(document).scrollTop(jQuery('#gforms_confirmation_message').offset().top);
          jQuery(document).trigger('gform_confirmation_loaded', [2]);
        }, 50);
      } else {
        jQuery('#gform_2').append(contents);
        if (window['gformRedirect']) gformRedirect();
      }
      jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [2, current_page]);
    });
  });
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [2, 1])
  });
</script>
```

Comment: No; for *this* you really should research yourself. Use the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), and [Mozilla Developer Network's JavaScript resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript) (among many, many others). If you don't understand something then please, by all means, come back and ask about *that* particular difficulty or misunderstanding (after searching the site first, of course).

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you David I will research it

Comment: @DavidThomas Maybe I should have been a little more specific. Can I add some code to make the script gather data from the input fields and send the form data to a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

It checks the form to see if it's okay to render, if all needs are met, it renders the form in the iframe.

To know what element does what: research the [Jquery Api](http://api.jquery.com/) and use some of your own brainlogic.

Comment: Maybe I should have been a little more specific. Can I add some code to make the script gather data from the input fields and send the form data to a server?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Just load the information from the input field, post it to your server using ajax and you're done.

Comment: Thats the part I dont understand. Ive tried reading a little but every thing I find is in english and when it comes to those matters my english fails me. Please explain a little so I understand the logic then I can try figuring it out on my own.

Comment: There lies the crux then. I'd suggest you brush up on your english where programming is concerned. Then the internet is rich.
To retrieve a value I usually use `document.getElementById('elementid').value` or you could use the jquery equivalent. Ajax posting is simple `$.ajax('url_to_post_to.php?x='+myvalue).done(function(data){document.getElementById('ajaxresult').innerHTML = data});`
I can't provide any more logic really...